# Quadratic Formula Calculator

Tags: python-3.x

Could someone please help me figure out where I went wrong with this very basic code I wrote this morning? Trying to write a calculator for the quadratic formula question on Python 3 but I get an error saying "NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined". It sort of makes sense, but then I do not know how else to put the square root in there. Is there some other function I should be using?

PS: I learn on my own off youtube and ebooks. So if you could please explain to me like I'm five, that would be awesome, thanks. I just started learning a couple days ago.

```
    # Quadratic Formula Calculator
    # What could possibly go wrong?
    
    # Define a, b, and c variables for the quad formula
    a = int(input("What is your 'a' variable? "))
    b = int(input("What is your 'b' variable? "))
    c = int(input("What is your 'c' variable? "))
    
    print(f"""
    Your quadratic formula result in + is...
    {((-b) + ((sqrt(b) ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)}
    """)
    
    print(f"""
    Your quadratic formula result in - is...
    {((-b) - ((sqrt(b) ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)}
    """)
```

Comment: the part in the sqrt should be `sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)` for the quadratic equation

Comment: `from math import sqrt`    or if you allow complex results `from cmath import sqrt`. sqrt not a built-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqrt` is not a built-in function of python. It is a function of the `math` module. So you must first import math.

The code must be:

```py
    import math
    a = int(input("What is your 'a' variable? "))
    b = int(input("What is your 'b' variable? "))
    c = int(input("What is your 'c' variable? "))
        
    print(f"""
    Your quadratic formula result in + is...
    {((-b) +  (math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)}
     """)
        
    print(f"""
    Your quadratic formula result in - is...
    {((-b) - (math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)}
    """)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `sqrt` function thus:

`import math`

and then use your square root like this:

`math.sqrt(9)`

which returns 3.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works! This is awesome. Could you please tell me what other things the "math" import (module?) covers? Or where I could look up a list? Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @CustardJesus First result of googling `python math`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Comment: the math functions are covered in https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html The doc may vary slightly depending on what python sub-version you're using.  Please accept the answer if it satisfied your question, too :)